# run a part of code php in other php file

Tags: php

I have a.php

```
    <?php
echo 'hello world';
echo 'MY NAME IS ZORO';
echo date('Y-m-d');
?>
```

and I have b.php and I want to get only code (echo date('Y-m-d');) from a.php.
How can I do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want only one line to print from multiple , try below code.

**a.php**

```
<?php
    $_GET["onlydate"] = true;
    include ('b.php');
?>
```

**b.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["onlydate"]) && $_GET["onlydate"]){
    echo date("Y-m-d");
}
else{
    echo 'hello world';
    echo 'MY NAME IS ZORO';
    echo date('Y-m-d');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you want only one line (block of code) from multiple.

**Funtions**

You can divide the code to functions and then call them as you wish.

File a.php:

```
<?php
    function printDate() {
        echo date('Y-m-d');
    }

    function printAll() {
        echo 'hello world';
        echo 'MY NAME IS ZORO';
        printDate();
    }
?>
```

File b.php:

```
<?php
    include 'a.php';
    printDate();
?>
```

**Shared file**

Other way is to make another file *c.php* with shared content and include it to files *a.php* and *b.php*.

File a.php:

```
<?php
    echo 'hello world';
    echo 'MY NAME IS ZORO';
    include 'c.php';
?>
```

File b.php:

```
<?php
    include 'c.php';
?>
```

File c.php:

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function of Php.

Put all your contents whatever you wish in `b.php`(in your case its echo date...) and then include `b.php` file in `a.php`.

Comment: although the OP states *I want to get only code (echo date('Y-m-d');)*. `include` will include all 3 lines, not just the `date()` line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the file handling. Then ignore all the code which you does not need in the a.php and then execute the  remaining code in b.php

Comment: You can read the http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp to understand the file handling. Here you have to see the example of line by line read.